# Visual Studio 2012 incorrectly runs IIS Express x32

Tags: visual-studio-2012, iis-7.5

I am running into an issue with Visual Studio 2012 with IIS Express x32 in local debug mode.

I can't figure out how to FORCE VS2012 x64 to debug with IIS Express x64. Task Man shows IIS Express 32 is always running.
My project returns error:

ould not load file or assembly  or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

thanks.
Bob

Comment: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3254745-allow-for-iis-express-64-bit-to-run-from-visual-st

Comment: @ta.speot.is - I've seen this hkey registry solution, but it doesn't work for me. IIS Express x32 is getting spawned by VS2012 when I run my project in debug or non-debug mode. There must be some issue on my laptop and/or in my VS configuration. I just don't understand. Thank you.